# How to convert STRING in ARRAY?

Tags: php, arrays, string

my string is:

```
$string = 'fecha[d]';
```

how I can convert this in:

```
$fecha[d] = null;
```

or

```
$fecha[d] = false;
```

or

```
$fecha[d] = '';
```

I see **filter_var_array()**, but I not found how used this to convert my string in array.

Thanks.

Comment: Try: `$string = 'fecha["d"]';
eval("$$string = NULL;");
print_r($fecha);`. But $string should be `fecha['d']`

Comment: oh, thanks, my problem is this var comming from GET, then I can´t run this risk: **$_GET['string']**

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KBnFkSgk, also you should delete your question, it's a bad question.

Comment: If you need to do what you said, you definitely are going the wrong way in programming...

Comment: Any time you find yourself needing variable variables, you're probably doing something wrong. You should be using associative arrays instead.

Comment: So you meant string in variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to parse it.

```
preg_match('/^(\w+)\[(.+)\]$/', $string, $match);
$var = $match[1];
$index = $match[2];
```

And you should keep the values in an associative array, not use a variable variable:

```
$myvars[$var][$index] = null;
```

But if you really want a variable variable it would be:

```
${$var}[$index] = null;
```

Comment: I need validate $o (O-rder of a list).
With the help of **strangeqargo** now I have:

   if(!empty($_GET['o'])){
    preg_match_all('/(.*)\[(.*?)\]/', $_GET['o'], $k);
    if(!empty($k[1]) && !empty($k[2]))$o[$k[1][0]] = $k[2][0];
    else $o = ARRAY();
    }
   else $o = ARRAY();

and this is a greath solution to my requeriment.
Thanks **strangeqargo** !! :)
ALSO THANKS to BARMAN! :)

Now I have: **ORDER BY name ASC** or **ORDER BY name DESC**

Some idea bether?

I try ADD REPLY, but this WEB no accept this from my... :'(

Comment: I think the last part of your answer should come first. That helps the OP better

Comment: @XHtml `$o[$k[1][0]]` should be `$o[$k[1]][$k[2]]`. It's easier if you assign these to variables like I did in my answer.